# Sql Getting Top 2 results in each classification

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I am new to sql and stuck in a problem.

Below is the sample of my table. This is not the exact table but a sample of what i am trying to achieve

```
   Name Classification Hits
    A      A1             2
    A      A2             3
    A      A3             4
    A      A4             8
    A      A5             9
    B      B1             9
    B      B2             3
    B      B3             4
    B      B4             8
    B      B5             9
    c      c1             8
    c      c2             9
    c      c3             4
    c      c4             8
    c      c5             9
    ...
```

And i am looking for the result based on top Hits . For example

```
Name Classification Hits
A      A4             8
A      A5             9
B      B1             9
B      B5             9
c      c2             9
c      c5             9
```

i have tried this query

```
SELECT  TOP (2) Name , Classification , Hits
FROM   Table4
Group By  Name , Classification , Hits
Order By Hits
```

But i am only getting two values. What i am doing wrong here any suggestions?

Comment: You are using Top(2) that's why only two records are coming

Comment: i thought the same @SyedSalmanRazaZaidi. But what should i do to get my result>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CTE with the `Row_Number()` function

```
;WITH CTE AS(
  SELECT Name,
         Classification,
         Hits,
         Row_Number() OVER(Partition by name ORDER BY Hits DESC) AS RowNum
  FROM Table4
  )

SELECT Name,
       Classification,
       Hits
FROM CTE
WHERE RowNum <= 2
ORDER BY Name, Hits
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6478e/4)

Comment: Good work, I had made the solution, but will not post as the answer is same using CTE...

Answer (score 0):

I'm working from memory so I'm not sure of the syntax, and there's probably a more efficient way to do this, but you'd want to do something like

```
;with rawdata as (
   select Name, Classification, Hits, 
          Row_number() over (partition by Name order by Hits desc) as x
)
select Name, Classification, Hits from rawdata where x < 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit - I'll figure out the comment system one of these days!

Answer (score 0):

This will also work. Without using `ROW_NUMBER(`).

```
Select a.* from MyTable as M1
Cross apply
(
    Select  top 2   * from Mytable m2
    where m1.name = m2.name
    order by m2.Hits desc
)as a
where a.Classification = m1.Classification
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3978d/1)

But I don't know about performance.

Comment: i am using sql server and getting an error cross apply not supported

Comment: I hope you are using SQL Server 2008. Correct?

Comment: The CROSS APPLY SQL construct or statement is not supported.

Comment: CROSS APPLY is available since SQL SERVER 2005. I wonder how you are getting this error. Make sure you are using Microsoft SQL Server 2008. You can check My Fiddle Demo, it is also in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: i am using sql server which is an express edition in visual studio

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio?

Comment: Hmmm, I am not able to get your error.  Please check this. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ec1c0a9b-a600-4837-88df-582688a377dd/the-outer-apply-sql-construct-or-statement-is-not-supported?forum=sqlreportingservices.

Comment: If you are facing issue with APPLY operator, then you can use answer of @Raj. It is also correct solution.